# Regular expression to match first occurrence of ip from an ifconfig eth0 output

Tags: regex, python-2.7

i am trying to match the first occurrence of ip from ifconfig eth0 output of a system. I tried the following regular expression but it did not work.

*ifconfig output*:

```
eth0   
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
inet addr:10.20.30.40  Bcast:10.20.30.254  Mask:255.255.255.0
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:66196498 errors:0 dropped:32831 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:61850152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:41122659013 (41.1 GB)  TX bytes:28800593238 (28.8 GB)
Interrupt:22 Memory:f6ae0000-f6b00000
```

*regular expression tried:*

```
re.match("^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$",output)

re.match(("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$"),output)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `re.match` is a reasonable way to do this.  One potential problem you might have had is to not use `DOTALL` mode.  Going by your input string, the first IP address does not occur on the first line, so we want dot to match across all lines.

```
input = "Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx\ninet addr:10.20.30.40  Bcast:10.20.30.254  Mask:255.255.255.0"

match = re.match(r'^.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', input, re.DOTALL)

if match:
    print "first IP: ", match.group(1)

first IP:  10.20.30.40
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addr:([\d.]+)`, i.e.:

```
x = """
eth0   
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
inet addr:10.20.30.40  Bcast:10.20.30.254  Mask:255.255.255.0
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:66196498 errors:0 dropped:32831 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:61850152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:41122659013 (41.1 GB)  TX bytes:28800593238 (28.8 GB)
Interrupt:22 Memory:f6ae0000-f6b00000
"""
m = re.findall("addr:([\d.]+)", x, re.IGNORECASE)
if m:
    print m[0]
# 10.20.30.40
```

---

- [Python2.7 Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QIR)
- [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jat95Y/1)

---

**Regex Explanation:**

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can also use `socket` to determine the local ip address:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("1.1.1.1", 80))
print s.getsockname()[0]
s.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach i can use in an another piece of code

Comment: @raman If my answer helped you,  please consider accepting it as the correct answer. Thank you.